# Unit testing in GNU Prolog

Tags: unit-testing, prolog, gnu-prolog

I'm trying to migrate my SWI Prolog application into the GNU Prolog. Unfortunately I have a problem with unit tests. In SWIPL we can simply use [plunit](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(%27packages/plunit.html%27)) module and write the test cases like the following one:

```
:- begin_tests(my_tests).
test(my_predicate_test) :- my_predicate(Result), assertion(Result == [foo, bar]).
test(second_test) :- foo(10, X), assertion(X == "hello world").
:- end_tests(my_tests).
```

But how to implement unit tests in GNU Prolog? Even some additional libraries like [crisp](https://github.com/khueue/crisp) are not available for gprolog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`lgtunit`](https://logtalk.org/manuals/devtools/lgtunit.html). Its main features are summarized [here](https://logtalk.org/tools.html#testing). Most of your tests  could be run as-is or easily converted. Using your example:

```
:- object(tests, extends(lgtunit)).

    :- uses(lgtunit, [assertion/1]).
    :- uses(user, [my_predicate/1, foo/2]).

    test(my_predicate_test) :-
        my_predicate(Result),
        assertion(Result == [foo, bar]).

    test(second_test) :-
        foo(10, X),
        assertion(X == "hello world").

:- end_object.
```

The tool supports multiple [test dialects](https://logtalk.org/manuals/devtools/lgtunit.html#test-dialects), some of them common to `plunit`. E.g.

```
:- object(tests, extends(lgtunit)).

    :- uses(user, [my_predicate/1, foo/2]).

    test(my_predicate_test, true(Result == [foo, bar]) :-
        my_predicate(Result).

    test(second_test, true(X == "hello world")) :-
        foo(10, X).

:- end_object.
```

Assuming that you're testing plain Prolog code (given that you're using GNU Prolog), Logtalk's Prolog standards [compliance suite](https://github.com/LogtalkDotOrg/logtalk3/tree/master/tests/prolog) provides plenty of examples.

You can also export test results in multiple industry standards such as TAP and xUnit and generate reports for easy browsing (see e.g. https://infradig.github.io/trealla/).

For further advise on testing, see also these [blog posts](https://logtalk.org/blog.html?tag=testing).